# adding summary row to the end of the table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I have a table with 4 columns. the table is as below

```
sampleId    totalAmount discount    netAmount
      1         120        40           80
      2         200        50           150
      3         400        100          300
```

Now i want the totals summary row at the bottom of the table. Please look at the image file below. how can i achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`UNION ALL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) as below

```
select cast(sampleId as char(10)) as sampleId, totalAmount,discount, netAmount
from tab
union all
select 'Total', sum(totalAmount),sum(discount), sum(netAmount)
from tab
```

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74c45/2/0) Demo**

1st  column is converted to varchar becouse you want to `Total` word atthe bottom. Columns types in `UNION` must be the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You may do `union all`

```
select * from tablename
union all 
select 'Totals' as sampleId,
sum(totalAmount) as totalAmount,
sum(discount) as discount,
sum(netAmount) as netAmount 
from tablename
```

Here is a demo

```
mysql> select * from test ;
+------+--------+----------+-----------+
| id   | amount | discount | net_total |
+------+--------+----------+-----------+
|    1 |    120 |       40 |        80 |
|    2 |    200 |       50 |       150 |
|    3 |    500 |      100 |       300 |
+------+--------+----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  select * from test union all select 'Totals' as id,sum(amount) as amount,sum(discount) as discount,sum(net_total) as net_total from test ;
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
| id     | amount | discount | net_total |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
| 1      |    120 |       40 |        80 |
| 2      |    200 |       50 |       150 |
| 3      |    500 |      100 |       300 |
| Totals |    820 |      190 |       530 |
+--------+--------+----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(sampleId,"Total") as sampleId, SUM(totalAmount), SUM(discount), SUM(netAmount)
    FROM tablename
        GROUP BY sampleId WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `group by modifiers` :

```
select Coalesce(sampleId, 'Total') `sampleId` , sum(totalAmount),sum(discount),sum(netAmount)
from t 
group by sampleId with rollup
```

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f1826/11

Here is a documentation on ROLLUP : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html